# Doubts on a custom loss function for regression problems

Tags: deep-learning, logistic-regression, loss-function, backpropagation, cross-entropy

From what I read, I know we don't use log loss or cross entropy for **regression** problems. However, the entire logic behind binary cross entropy(say) is to firstly squeeze the y_hat between 0 and 1 (actually the sigmoid does this - hence it's compatible with binary cross entropy) and then we can measure loss = - y_actual*(log(y_hat)) , where in multi class classification y_actual becomes 1 and y_hat is some number between 0 and 1. All this is fine, something I learnt during multi class classification of CIFAR-10 dataset. I had a doubt.

What if, say I have y_true = 10 , and y_hat1 and y_hat2 as 9.5 and 10.5 . If I don't care about under or over predicting(for these 2 predictions), I can use a **custom loss function** where I:

1. find absolute difference between y_actual and y_hat
2. create **new y_hat = y_actual - abs(y_actual - y_hat)** . This doesn't become 'new' y_hat, just that it's used for computation ahead.
3. Normalize y_hat(new) and y_true, w.r.t y_true. Eg : if y_actual = 10 , y_hat = 10.5 , then y_hat now becomes **9.5(=10 - abs(10 - 10.5))** and say y_hat_norm is now 0.95, and y_true_norm is 1 ( after normalization)
4. compute  loss as 1*log(0.95)

In principle this should work similar as log loss concept , right? But for regression problems. If I don't care about separate weightage to overpredictions or underpredictions, is there any disadvantage to using this approach?

**EDIT**: Initially I started it off as an experiment - a way to 'bridge' the so called different metrics.

I eventually realised something.

**Case 1**: y_true =100, y_pred= 80 ; [loss = -log(0.8) ] .

**Case 2**: y_true = 40, y_pred= 20 [loss = -log(0.5) ] .

Higher values are penalized less for same error. This isn't helping 'my' case, but certainly is a very interesting metric if a problem statement comes up where as magnitude of truth increases, we care less and less about making huge errors. If your problem has tendencies of such 'relative performances' , this metric might be useful. would appreciate further comments/corrections!

Comment: what is the advantage of this approach?

Comment: edited the original answer